# JavaScript code problem with invalid output

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I need help finding the problem to my JavaScript code. The code outputs 'invalid day' but instead It should be 'open.

```js
function workingHours(input) {
  let hour = Number(input[0]);
  let day = input[1];

  if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Thursday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday") {
    if (hour >= 10 && hour <= 18) {
      console.log("open");
    } else if (hour < 10 || hour >= 19) {
      console.log("closed");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid hour");
    }
  } else if (day == "Sunday") {
    if (hour <= 23 && hour >= 0) {
      console.log("closed");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid hour");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("invalid day");
  }
}

workingHours("11", "Tuesday")
```

I tried making the input for 'day' all in lowercases and the required values in the 'if' also in lowercase  but still didn't work. I am new so I'm sorry if I am talking nonsense.

Comment: You're passing two string parameters (`'11'` and `'Tuesday'`)to `workingHours()`, but the function is looking for a single array, `input`. Use your debugger to see what you're actually passing and what your variables are.

Comment: change `workingHours(input) {` to `workingHours(...input) {`

Answer (score 1):

In JS the parameters are coming into a function not as an array but as separate variables.

If you make the following change to the function params, the code works as you expect.

```js
function workingHours(hour, day){
    if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Thursday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday"){
        if (hour >= 10 && hour <= 18){
            console.log("open");
        } else if (hour < 10 || hour >= 19) {
            console.log("closed");
        } else{
            console.log("invalid hour");
        }
    } else if (day == "Sunday"){
        if (hour <= 23 && hour >= 0){
            console.log("closed");
        } else{
            console.log("invalid hour");
        }
    } else{
        console.log("invalid day");
    }
}

workingHours(11, "Tuesday");
```

Answer (score 1):

- I think the solution is really simple, how ever what you need is, you should know how you can debug your code. You can know more about it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).
- What is important here is that, for your example, if you have try to debug your code, then you will find out that  `workingHours(input)`, has only one input.
- Potential way to check for what your below line is storing by, using `console.log()`. Output will Agrgument `11`, will be store from their indexes which will make, `hour` to have value `1` and `day` to contain value `1`.

```js
let hour = Number(input[0]);
let day = input[1];
```

- Just FYR, you can do this also by putting `debugger` at start of function, to check how values for `hour` and `day` are passed.
- So, Once you find the root cause for your problem, you could try to think of different approach, which here is needed to have **Arguments needs to be added** to store day value and access them both directly.
- You can visit [this](https://raygun.com/learn/javascript-debugging-tips) website for check outing some debugging tips.

```js
function workingHours(hour, day) {
  hour = Number(hour);
  if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Thursday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday") {
    if (hour >= 10 && hour <= 18) {
      console.log("open");
    } else if (hour < 10 || hour >= 19) {
      console.log("closed");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid hour");
    }
  } else if (day == "Sunday") {
    if (hour <= 23 && hour >= 0) {
      console.log("closed");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid hour");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("invalid day");
  }
}

workingHours("11", "Tuesday")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive two different values, you can just use 2 parameters then you won't need this part:

```
let hour = Number(input[0]);
let day = input[1];
```

It would become to this:

```
function workingHours(hour, day){
    if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Thursday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday"){
        if (hour >= 10 && hour <= 18){
            console.log("open");
        } else if (hour < 10 || hour >= 19) {
            console.log("closed");
        } else{
            console.log("invalid hour");
        }
    } else if (day == "Sunday"){
        if (hour <= 23 && hour >= 0){
            console.log("closed");
        } else{
            console.log("invalid hour");
        }
    } else{
        console.log("invalid day");
    }
}

workingHours("11", "Tuesday")
```

I would recommend you to take a look on how functions work. On [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) you can find a nice documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score -1):

Your workingHours function takes 1 argument and you're passing 2 arguments. Inside the function, you're assuming that input would be an array but instead, you're passing 2 separate arguments.
Make this change where you're calling the function.
workingHours(["11", "Tuesday"])